# trying to organize bootstrap cards using grid system horizontally

Tags: html, vue.js, grid

as the screenshot shows i'm trying to make one card occupy two places in two different rows but i cant make it horizontal

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofeEI.png)tps://i.stack.imgur.com/Mi9PZ.png

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide information if you have written any html or css for this. That will be useful to provide to correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In gerneral you can try grid system of css e.g in element UI you can do something like this.

```
 <el-row :gutter="20">
  <el-col :span="6"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col>
  <el-col :span="6"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col>
  <el-col :span="12"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col> 
</el-row>
  <el-row :gutter="20">
  <el-col :span="12"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col>
  <el-col :span="6"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col>
  <el-col :span="6"><div class="grid-content bg-purple"></div></el-col>
</el-row>
```

Check live example here
[Element UI layout example](https://codepen.io/ketanmokariya/pen/mdMWrZj)

you can check element UI official document for more info [Element UI layout](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/layout)